# Newtonsoft c# delete entire node if properties match

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a Json like that (the real is much bigger with hundreds of nodes) :

```
{
  "label": "Root",
  "root": [
    {
      "label": "ROOT1",
      "debug": false,
      "title": "",
      "subtitle": "",
      "sub-items": [
        {
      "label": "",
      "debug": false,
      "title": "",
      "subtitle": "",
      "sub-items": [
        {
          "label": "",
          "tc": 3.5,
          "sub-items": [],

          "title": "",
          "description": "",
          "mediaUrl": "",
          "mediaLoopUrl": "",

        }
        ],

        "visible": false,

       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to delete an entire node, if the property "Visible" is "false". I know how to delete juste the "Visible" (based on my research), but I don't know how to delete the entire node...

I tried that to find the node I want to delete :

```
static private JObject RemoveNoVisibleInJson(JObject node) {
            string subItemVar = null;

            if (node["sub-items"] != null)
            {
                subItemVar = "sub-items";
            }
            else if (node["root"] != null)
            {
                subItemVar = "root";
            }
            int i = 0;
            if (subItemVar != null) {
                i = 0;
                foreach (JObject item in node[subItemVar])
                {   
                    Console.WriteLine(item["visible"]);
                    if (item["visible"] != null && item["visible"].ToString() == "False") {
                        //Delete ITEM
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (item["sub-items"] != null)
                    {
                        RemoveNoVisibleInJson(item);
                    }
                    else if (item["root"] != null)
                    {
                        RemoveNoVisibleInJson(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return node;
        }
```

But I don't know how to delete "item" from "node".

How can I do that ? Thanks !

Comment: Delete from what? Is this json serialized into object form or are you trying to modify the plain json itself?

Comment: What do you mean by _entire node_?

Comment: @ESG I'm using a string I deserialize to a JObject

Comment: @Adam the "sub-item" entirely

Comment: Please, explain which item and node you want to delete, based on your json example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Remove()` on the node you want to remove

example:

```cs
foreach (JObject item in node[subItemVar].ToList()) // Force ToList because we can't modify the children while it's enumerating
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["visible"]);
    if (item["visible"] != null && item["visible"].ToString() == "False")
    {
        item.Remove();
        continue; // Do no more processing on this node
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's working ! Thank you very much, I was so close but so far at the same time ! Thank you !